# Do I have to make my own LUIS entity to recognize the word "latest"

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am currently using the prebuilt entity ORDINAL and it serves very well in recognizing the words FIRST and LAST. However, from tests, I see that my users use the word "latest" and it doesn't recognize it as an ORDINAL.

Should I just make my own entity then? Any help to point me to the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this instance you have three options ahead of you, two of which are in LUIS itself.

#### LUIS: Option 1 - Simple Entity

- Create a simple entity in your application and add `latest` and its synonyms to your LUIS application.
- Benefits include less code debt, being able to label tokens manually, and using machine learning to recognize `latest` and its synonyms *(note: you still have to provide the synonyms for LUIS to recognize)*
- Cons include one less entity to use in your application (current limit for any combination of simple, hierarchical and composite entities is 30 per application).

#### LUIS: Option 2 - List Entity

- Create a list entity in your application and add `latest` as the canonical form of a sublist with its synonyms as values in the list for matching.
- Benefits include RegEx matching, abstracted away from your application. LUIS will recognize any token that already exists in the list entity.
- Cons include losing one list entity for *one* word with a finite set of synonyms (current limit for list entities is 50 per application). You will have to add each token manually to the sublist for it to be recognized. Users are unable to label tokens with a list entity. *Not used in the machine learning aspect of LUIS, does not help improve intent prediction scores.*

#### Application level: RegExp/sub-string parsing

- Create a token extractor (using RegExp or some other technique) to recognize the word `latest` and its synonyms
- Benefits for this include fewer expenditure of LUIS resources (entities and list entities), and less importantly, perhaps a minuscule reduction in the time it takes to receive results from LUIS.
- Cons for this include increased code debt due to the matching you have to perform in your application.

Comment: I ended up with Option 1 on top of an ordinal entity. So when I process it, I do  TryFindEntity twice then out it into the same variable.

if (result.TryFindEntity("ordinal", out ordinalEntityRecommendation) || (result.TryFindEntity("myordinal", out ordinalEntityRecommendation)))